# How can I ftp multiple files?

Tags: ftp

I have two unix servers in which I need to ftp some files.
The directory structure is almost same except a slight difference, like:

```
server a                 server b
miabc/v11_0/a/b/c/*.c    miabc/v75_0/a/b/c/
miabc/v11_0/xy/*.h       miabc/v11_0/xy/
```

There are many modules:

```
miabc
mfabc
```

The directory structure inside them is same in both the servers except the 11_0 and 75_0. And directory structure in side different modules is different

How can I FTP all the files in all modules into the corresponding module in second server b by any of scripting languages like awk, Perl, shell, ksh using FTP?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say if you want to go with Perl, you have to use Net::FTP.

Once, I needed a script that diffs a directory/file structure on an FTP
server with a corresponding directory/file structure on a local harddisk,
which lead me to write [this script](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/perl/scripts/ftp_diff.html). I don't know if it is efficient or elegant, but you might find one or another
idea in it.

hth / Rene

Answer (score 0):

*See you need to use correct path of directory where you want to send files.
You can create small script with php .
php provide good ftp functions.using php you can easily ftp your file. but before that, once check your ftp settings of IIS server or file zilla 
I have used following code for sending files on ftp this is in php :-*

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($FTP_HOST) or die("Couldn't connect to ".$FTP_HOST); 
    $login_result =ftp_login($conn_id, $FTP_USER, $FTP_PW);
    ftp_fput($conn_id, $from, $files, $mode)   // ths is the function to put files on ftp
```

*This code is just for reference , go through php manual before using it.*

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a combination of [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod), [lftp](http://tutorials.papamike.ca/pub/lftp.html) and a recursive function to walk the directory structure.

Answer (score -1):

If the file system supports symlinking or hardlinking, I would use a simple `wget` to mirror the ftp server. in one of them when you're wgetting just hack the directory `v11_0` to point to `75_0`, wget won't know the difference.

server a:

1. go to /project/servera
2. wget the whole thing. (this should place them all in /project/servera/miabc/v11_0)

server b:

1. go to /project/serverb
2. create a directory /project/serverb/miabc/75_0, link it to /project/servera/v11_0:

   - `ln -s /project/serverb/miabc/75_0 /project/servera/v11_0`
3. wget serverb, this will be followed when wget tries to cwd into in 75_0 it will find itself in /project/servera/v11_0

Don't make the project harder than it needs to be: read the docs on wget, and ln. If wget doesn't follow symbolic links, file a bug report, and use a hard link if your FS supports it.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you really want rsync instead. I'd try to avoid any programming in solving this problem.

Comment: Rysnc doesn't fundamentally solve the problem of merging /different/ directory structures. It is just a massively more efficient transport.

Comment: It's not a different directory structure according to the question. They just have a different base directory. I use rsync in that situation all the time.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you could login on any of the server first and go to the appropraite path miabc/v75_0/a/b/c/ . From here you need to do a sftp to the other server.

1. sftp user@servername
2. Go to the appropraiate path which files needs to be transferred.
3. write the command mget *

Comment: @sachin...i know how to do ftp but the problem is there are 1000's of files in multiple directories.so its a very difficult task to go to every directory and doing mget.

Comment: I dont know the reason for downvoting me. Glad to know it. But if you have a list of absolute paths of all directories, then this approach will work inside a for loop iterates on ls count